# How to apply Javascript mouseover css effects to all elements with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I want to increase the opacity to 1 for `img__text` when the user hovers over `text__container`.
I have tried achieving this with strictly CSS by trying to effect the child of `text__container` like so, `#text__container ~ .img__text` then applying the desired CSS effects.

**Index.html**

```html
<div class="gallery__container">
  <div>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="./images/image1.png" alt="">
    <div id="text__container">
      <span class="img__text">Shake & Shot</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="./images/image2.png" alt="">
    <div id="text__container">
      <span class="img__text">It's On</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="./images/image3.png" alt="">
    <div id="text__container">
      <span class="img__text">Shake & Shot</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="./images/image4.png" alt="">
    <div id="text__container">
      <span class="img__text">Shake & Shot</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="./images/image5.png" alt="">
    <div id="text__container">
      <span class="img__text">Shake & Shot</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="./images/image6.png" alt="">
    <div id="text__container">
      <span class="img__text">Shake & Shot</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Style.scss**

```css
//Gallery
  .gallery__container {
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    div {
      background-color: #000;
      width: 49%;
      margin: 0 0 2% 0;
      height: 665px;
      display: grid;
      
      img {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        align-content: center;
        transition: 0.8s ease-out;
        opacity: 1;
        &:hover {
          transition: 0.8s ease-in;
          cursor: pointer;
          opacity: 0.5;
        }
      }
      #text__container {
        border: 1px solid red;
        text-align: center;
        align-self: center;
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: transparent;
        transition: 0.8s ease-out;
        &:hover {
          transition: 0.8s ease-in;
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }
        .img__text {
          border: 1px solid red;
          text-align: center;
          align-self: center;
          z-index: 3;
          color: #fff;
          font-family: $main-font;
          font-size: 2rem;
          width: 50%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          transition: 0.8s ease-out;
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Script.js**

```js
//Variables
var imgContainer = document.getElementById('text__container');
var imgText = document.getElementsByClassName('img__text');

for (i = 0; i < imgText.length; i++) {
  imgContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    imgText[i].style.opacity = "1";
    imgText[i].style.transition = "0.8s ease-in";
  });

  imgContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    imgText[i].style.opacity = "0";
    imgText[i].style.transition = "0.8s ease-out";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple elements with the same id - change that to a clas. Also your code needs to use `let` in the loop if you want to assign events. Finally it's `mouseout` not `mouseleave`.

This works.

```js
var imgContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('text__container');
var imgText = document.getElementsByClassName('img__text');

for (let i = 0; i < imgText.length; i++) {
  imgContainer[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    imgText[i].style.opacity = "1";
    imgText[i].style.transition = "0.8s ease-in";
  });

  imgContainer[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    imgText[i].style.opacity = "0";
    imgText[i].style.transition = "0.8s ease-out";
  });
}
```

```css
.gallery__container {
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    div {
      background-color: #000;
      width: 49%;
      margin: 0 0 2% 0;
      height: 665px;
      display: grid;
      
      img {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        align-content: center;
        transition: 0.8s ease-out;
        opacity: 1;
        &:hover {
          transition: 0.8s ease-in;
          cursor: pointer;
          opacity: 0.5;
        }
      }
      .text__container {
        border: 1px solid red;
        text-align: center;
        align-self: center;
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: transparent;
        transition: 0.8s ease-out;
        &:hover {
          transition: 0.8s ease-in;
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }
        .img__text {
          border: 1px solid red;
          text-align: center;
          align-self: center;
          z-index: 3;
          color: #fff;
          font-family: $main-font;
          font-size: 2rem;
          width: 50%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          transition: 0.8s ease-out;
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="gallery__container">
    <div>
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
      <div class="text__container">
        <span class="img__text">Shake & Shot</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
      <div class="text__container">
        <span class="img__text">It's On</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
      <div class="text__container">
        <span class="img__text">It's On</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="gallery__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
      <div class="text__container">
        <span class="img__text">It's On</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```